# macro using `\tag` throws error in `beamer` but not in `amsart` class

Tags: beamer, csname, tag

The code fragment below throws this error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.9 \end{align}
```

when run as is.   If I change the class to `amsart` it runs without error.
Could somebody please explain why beamer doesn't like it?  And how to fix the problem?    Thanks!

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
    \def\tagPrime#1{\tag{\ref{#1}$\empty^\prime$}\label{#1Prime}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \label{myTag}
    a = b \\
    a = b
    \tagPrime{myTag}
    \end{align} 
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `\protect` in front of `\ref` (and probably `\ref*` is better, not to make a useless link).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\tagPrime[1]{%
  \tag{\protect\ref*{#1}$'$}%
  \label{#1Prime}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
\label{myTag}
a = b \\
\tagPrime{myTag}
a = b
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\eqref{myTag} and \eqref{myTagPrime}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an arguably simpler solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{myTag}
a = b \\
a = b
\tag*{(\ref{myTag}')}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image]